# Jquery balance Update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want a jquery code that update balance in a table and also update it in database.
i-e if profit  = 0 then it should increase upto 0.48 in 30 days

Comment: Are you sure the data is structured properly as per server side processing docs?

Comment: i have attached the image of how data is coming. plz check it

Comment: is there any one who can help me out